# Apply css just to a part of the image

Tags: css

I want to apply the following css to just a part of an image, let's say 50% of the image, is there any way to do that?

```
.blurred
{
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(12px);
    transform: scale(2) translateY(20px);
}
```

In this case I'm apply this css to the image with the id "slider", but it's applying it to the whole image, what I want is to apply it just to part of the original image.

```
<div class="blurred"></div>
    <img width="20%" height="10% !important" style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:1%;z-index:0" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <b><div class="font-adapt-big" style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:1%;font-size: 32px;z-index:200">Benvenuto nel gestionale Wolftank!</div>
    <div class="font-adapt-medium" style="position:absolute;top:35%;left:1%;font-size: 18px;z-index:200;max-width:30%">Wolftank-Adisa Holding AG è la società madre di un gruppo internazionale che si concentra sui servizi di protezione ambientale per terreni e strutture contaminate, sulla bonifica e sul monitoraggio di parchi di cisterne (su larga scala), nonché sui servizi di ingegneria a servizio completo per stazioni di GNL e di benzina.</div></b>
```

Comment: Generally speaking you don't apply css to an image per se, but to it's container html element, maybe an <img> or a <div> with a background image.  It's seems like you want to apply a blur effect to a portion of an image which to me translates to  applying a blur effect to an absolutely positioned <div> that overlays the portion of the image you need blurred.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well. You can't do what you want with a single image, but there may be another solution.

Comment: Added the html code, what I want is the blur to be applied just to the image and not on the text which is on the image (the text has a z-index of 200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it to 50% of the image specifically, but you can apply it to an identical image placed above it. These both would be left inside a container `div` to ensure responsiveness.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
width: 298px;
height: 298px;
position: relative;
height: auto;
border: solid 2px black;
}
.container img {
height: 100%;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
}
.filter {
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
color: red;
left: 0;
z-index: 3;
filter: hue-rotate(180deg) blur(2px);
height: 99%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.filter img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://cb.scene7.com/is/image/Crate/LFFullMoonVaseClaySHS20/$web_plp_card_mobile$/200115091429/full-moon-white-clay-vase.jpg">
<div class="filter">
<img src="https://cb.scene7.com/is/image/Crate/LFFullMoonVaseClaySHS20/$web_plp_card_mobile$/200115091429/full-moon-white-clay-vase.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your `img`'s style to a div. Then reduce the size accordingly.

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  height: 20%;
  width: 5%;
  position:absolute;
  top:12%;
  left:1%;
  z-index:201;
}

img{
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  position:absolute;
  top:12%;
  left:1%;
  z-index:200;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="Logo">
    <b><div class="font-adapt-big" style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:1%;font-size: 32px;z-index:200">Benvenuto nel gestionale Wolftank!</div>
    <div class="font-adapt-medium" style="position:absolute;top:35%;left:1%;font-size: 18px;z-index:200;max-width:30%">Wolftank-Adisa Holding AG è la società madre di un gruppo internazionale che si concentra sui servizi di protezione ambientale per terreni e strutture contaminate, sulla bonifica e sul monitoraggio di parchi di cisterne (su larga scala), nonché sui servizi di ingegneria a servizio completo per stazioni di GNL e di benzina.</div></b>
</div>
```